# linear-gradient css in jsx

Tags: css, reactjs, jsx

I downloaded a template from somewhere and trying to convert it to a react component, but one thing that I got stuck on, I am not able to get what `linear-gradient` is for in this css and how can I modify this to work in jsx inline style.

```js
let component = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (

      <div className="container" style={{boxSizing: 'border-box', width: 600, height: 340, margin: '0 auto', position: 'relative', WebkitPerspective: 1000, MozPerspective: 1000, perspective: 1000, MozTransform: 'perspective(1400px)', msTransform: 'perspective(1400px)', WebkitTransformStyle: 'preserve-3d', MozTransformStyle: 'preserve-3d', transformStyle: 'preserve-3d', WebkitPerspectiveOrigin: 'right', MozPerspectiveOrigin: 'right', perspectiveOrigin: 'right'}}>
        <div className="card" style={{boxSizing: 'border-box', width: 600, height: 340, boxShadow: '0 27px 55px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .7), 0 17px 17px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .5)', position: 'relative', WebkitTransform: 'rotate(0deg)', MozTransform: 'rotate(0deg)', msTransform: 'rotate(0deg)', transform: 'rotate(0deg)', WebkitTransformOrigin: '100% 0%', MozTransformOrigin: '100% 0%', msTransformOrigin: '100% 0%', transformOrigin: '100% 0%', WebkitTransformStyle: 'preserve-3d', MozTransformStyle: 'preserve-3d', transformStyle: 'preserve-3d', transition: '.8s ease-in-out'}}>
          <div className="front" style={{boxSizing: 'border-box', position: 'absolute', top: 0, left: 0, width: '100%', height: '100%', background: 'white', WebkitBackfaceVisibility: 'hidden', MozBackfaceVisibility: 'hidden', backfaceVisibility: 'hidden', display: 'flex', WebkitJustifyContent: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', WebkitAlignItems: 'center', alignItems: 'center', zIndex: 2, WebkitTransform: 'rotateY(0deg)', MozTransform: 'rotateY(0deg)', msTransform: 'rotateY(0deg)', transform: 'rotateY(0deg)'}}>
            <div className="logo" style={{boxSizing: 'border-box', width: 200, height: 200, position: 'relative', background: 'linear-gradient(45deg, #F5AF69 50%, #F4EED7 50.9%),
  linear-gradient(90deg, #FC5135 50%, #4E203C 50%),
  linear-gradient(-45deg, #F5AF69 50%, #E8D9A0 50.9%), 
  linear-gradient(#FC5135 50%, #4E203C 50%),
  linear-gradient(-45deg, #F5AF69 50%, #E8D9A0 50.9%),
  linear-gradient(90deg, #FC5135 50%, #4E203C 50%),
  linear-gradient(45deg, #FC5135 50%, #F5AF69 50.9%)', backgroundSize: '50px 50px, 100px 50px, 50px 50px, 200px 100px, 50px 50px, 100px 50px, 50px 50px', backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat', backgroundPosition: '0 0, 50px 0px, 150px 0, 0 50px, 0 150px, 50px 150px, 150px 150px'}}><span style={{boxSizing: 'border-box', display: 'block', background: '#4E203C', width: 29, height: 32, position: 'absolute', top: '99.5px', left: 130, borderRadius: '0 50% 50% 0'}} /></div>
          </div>
          <div className="back" style={{boxSizing: 'border-box', position: 'absolute', top: 0, left: 0, width: '100%', height: '100%', background: 'white', WebkitBackfaceVisibility: 'hidden', MozBackfaceVisibility: 'hidden', backfaceVisibility: 'hidden', WebkitTransform: 'rotateY(-180deg)', MozTransform: 'rotateY(-180deg)', msTransform: 'rotateY(-180deg)', transform: 'rotateY(-180deg)', fontFamily: '"Arimo", sans-serif'}}>
            <h1 style={{boxSizing: 'border-box', color: '#FC5135', textTransform: 'uppercase', fontWeight: 400, lineHeight: 1, marginTop: 110, textAlign: 'center', fontSize: 40}}>Helen Parker<span style={{boxSizing: 'border-box', color: '#4E203C', display: 'block', fontSize: '.45em', letterSpacing: 3}}>design <i style={{boxSizing: 'border-box', fontStyle: 'normal', textTransform: 'none', fontFamily: '"Playfair Display", serif'}}>&amp;</i> photography</span></h1>
            <ul style={{boxSizing: 'border-box', margin: 0, width: '100%', listStyle: 'none', position: 'absolute', bottom: 30, left: 0, padding: '0 1%'}}>
              <li style={{boxSizing: 'border-box', width: '31.3333333333%', margin: '0 1%', float: 'left', padding: 10, border: '2px solid #FC5135', borderRadius: 4, position: 'relative', textAlign: 'center', color: '#4E203C'}}>+1-111-111-11-11</li>
              <li style={{boxSizing: 'border-box', width: '31.3333333333%', margin: '0 1%', float: 'left', padding: 10, border: '2px solid #FC5135', borderRadius: 4, position: 'relative', textAlign: 'center', color: '#4E203C'}}>my-email@email.com</li>
              <li style={{boxSizing: 'border-box', width: '31.3333333333%', margin: '0 1%', float: 'left', padding: 10, border: '2px solid #FC5135', borderRadius: 4, position: 'relative', textAlign: 'center', color: '#4E203C'}}>my-site.com</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: your snippet is not running

Comment: What @AKASHPANDEY meant it that the snippet in your question is not working. Here is the explanation about snippets and how to use them: https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Comment: can someone please edit this to make it working, as I can't figure it out, how make a react snippet work

Comment: @MoshFeu added this snippet to just for viewing purpose, as there is nothing to run in this. My code is not running because of 'linear-gradient' thing in this, one can just look at this and tell me the problem about this so that I can fix it.

Comment: @Rizvan did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: @NathanL I could find a solution to this, I guess there is no equivalent to this in jsx, I had to remove it and proceed with some other css provided by our design team.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use inline styles you could do:

`<div style={{backgroundImage: 'linear-gradient(to right, #439bfd, #73b3fb)'}}...`

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck on the same problem, I found this solution which may be more of a hack than an actual clean solution. I added the code in a css page, and then I inspected the element.
For example : for * background: linear-gradient(to right, #000 0%,  #000 50%, #fff 50% #fff 100%)*; if you inspect it using inspect element, you will find : *-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(#000), color-stop(50%, #000), color-stop(50%, #fff))* .
So just add this last line in the inline style of your react compenent:

```
<div className="card" style={{background:"-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(#000), color-stop(50%, #000), color-stop(50%, #fff))"}}/>
```

for my example, I used this one above instead of :

```
<div className="card" style={{background: linear-gradient(to right, #000 0%,  #000 50%, #fff 50% #fff 100%)"}}/>
```

So in conclusion, add this to a css file, it will work, see the output in the "inspect element", and use it and edit it as you like in the inline style of your react js component.